# yii framework doesnt use the correct CSS

Tags: php, css, yii, vagrant, yii-extensions

I'm working with yii framework I have installed the yii booster extensions and I work with vagrant. My friend also works on this project, however the problem is that the application doesn't use the correct CSS. Instead, it uses a CSS saved in cache.

Here how it is: There is a folder at: `www\SVN\wwwroot\public\assets`
it contains some folders with weird names, one of them contains all the bootstrap CSS and everything belonging to bootstrap. This is wrong because this art is regenerated every-time I regenerate vagrant. The problem is I am using the correct CSS unless I do a (delete cookie cash) sometimes I get the correct CSS sometimes I get the wrong CSS, but all the other people using this they get the wrong CSS, unless I change it for them manually on assests folder, which is totally wrong because every time I update my workstation using svn it should apply the new lay out to other prople as well but it doesn't work.

Here is my main config:

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the main Web application configuration.
 *
 * Any writable CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
 * It is constructed the following way:
 *    main.php = return the main settings
 *                  unless overwritten by the local main settings if available
 *                  unless overwritten by the test settings if available
 *                  unless overwritten by the local test settings if available
 * (mergeArray: latter will overwrite the former, see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMap#mergeArray-detail)
 *
 * @author Yii, adapted by Robbert <Paulussen@Momentum-Technologies.nl>
 * @since release 1.0 (sprint 1)
 */
// Set up path variables to reflect the directory structure
// $WEBHOME/                     -- doePath // = wwwroot
// $WEBHOME/public/              -- webrootPath
// $WEBHOME/private/protected/   -- protectedPath
// $WEBHOME/private/runtime/     -- runtimePath

$pathToDoeDirectory  = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../..'); // = wwwroot
$privatePath         = $pathToDoeDirectory . '/private/';
$protectedPath       = $pathToDoeDirectory . '/private/protected/';
$runtimePath         = $pathToDoeDirectory . '/private/runtime/';
$publicPath          = $pathToDoeDirectory . '/public/';
$webrootPath         = $publicPath;
$vendorPath          = '/vagrant/vendor/';

/**
 * Namespace MTE
 */
Yii::setPathOfAlias('MTE', $protectedPath);

// used by the themeUrl of widgetFactory settings, in case the DOE is in a subdirectory
$baseUrl = (isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])) ? str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', realpath('.')) : '';

//define('EOL','<br/>');
//echo '$pathToCcsDirectory = ' . $pathToCcsDirectory . PHP_EOL;
//echo '$privatePath = ' . $privatePath . PHP_EOL;
//echo '$protectedPath = ' . $protectedPath . PHP_EOL;
//echo '$runtimePath = ' . $runtimePath . PHP_EOL;
//echo '$publicPath = ' . $publicPath . PHP_EOL;
//echo '$webrootPath = ' . $webrootPath . PHP_EOL;
/** the following defines path aliases using:   Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');
 * usage e.g.  ... Yii::getPathOfAlias('runtimePath') ...
 */
Yii::setPathOfAlias('doePath', $pathToDoeDirectory);
Yii::setPathOfAlias('privatePath', $privatePath);
Yii::setPathOfAlias('publicPath', $publicPath);
Yii::setPathOfAlias('protectedPath', $protectedPath);
Yii::setPathOfAlias('runtimePath', $runtimePath);
Yii::setPathOfAlias('webrootPath', $webrootPath);
Yii::setPathOfAlias('vendorPath', $vendorPath);
Yii::setPathOfAlias('booster', $vendorPath . 'clevertech/yii-booster/src/'); // a twitter bootstrap library
//Yii::setPathOfAlias('booster', $publicPath . 'css/yii-booster/src/'); // a twitter bootstrap library

$config_database = require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/database.php');

$config_main = array(
    'sourceLanguage' => 'en', // for i18N
    'timeZone'       => 'Europe/Amsterdam',
    'basePath'       => $protectedPath,
    // override the default of Yii
    'runtimePath'    => $runtimePath,
    'name'           => Yii::t('systemwide', 'DOEN - DOssier opvolg- EN actiesysteem'),
    //'theme'=>'bootstrap',
    'preload'        => array(
        'log',
        'translate', // for i18N
        'booster', //Yii-Booster, a twitter bootstrap library
    ),
    'behaviors' => array(
        'onBeginRequest' => array(
            'class'  => 'application.components.modulesloader',),
    ), // for i18N
    // autoloading model and component classes, Note that importing a directory does not import any of its subdirectories!
    'import' => array(
        'application.components.*',
        'application.models.*',
        'application.modules.rights.*',
        'application.modules.rights.components.*',
        'application.modules.translate.TranslateModule',
        'booster.helpers.TbHtml',
        'booster.helpers.TbArray',
        'booster.behaviors.TbWidget',
        'booster.widgets.*'
    ),
    'modules' => array(
        'rights' => array(
            'install'        => false, // Whether to install rights.
            'userNameColumn' => 'login', // Name of the user name column in the database.
            'userClass'      => 'RightsModuleUser', // extended User model
            'cssFile'        => '/MTE/modules/rights/default.css', // custom css for rights module
            'superuserName'  => 'MTeAdmin', // doe_user.login of the user with super user privileges. Default 'Admin'
        /* more options */
//          'appLayout'          => 'application.views.layouts.main', // Application layout.
//          'authenticatedName'  => 'Authenticated',                // Name of the authenticated user role.
//          'baseUrl'            => '/rights',                      // Base URL for Rights. Change if module is nested.
//          'debug'              => false,                          // Whether to enable debug mode.
//          'displayDescription' => true,                           // Whether to use item description instead of name.
//          'enableBizRule'      => true,                           // Whether to enable authorization item business rules.
//          'enableBizRuleData'  => false,                          // Whether to enable data for business rules.
//          'flashErrorKey'      => 'RightsError',                  // Key to use for setting error flash messages.
//          'flashSuccessKey'    => 'RightsSuccess',                // Key to use for setting success flash messages.
//          'layout'             => 'rights.views.layouts.main',    // Layout to use for displaying Rights.
//          'userIdColumn'       => 'id',                           // Name of the user id column in the database.
        ),
        'translate',
        'components'     => array(
            //use component to store the cookies
            'Cookies' => array(
                'class'      => 'application.components.CookiesHelper'
            ),
            // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
            'urlManager' => array(
                'urlFormat'      => 'path',
                'showScriptName' => false,
                'rules'          => array(
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'              => '<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'          => '<controller>/<action>',
                ),
            ),
            'errorHandler'                           => array(
                // use 'site/error' action to display errors
                'errorAction'    => 'site/error',
            ),
            'log'            => array(
                'class'  => 'CLogRouter',
                'routes' => array(
                    array(
                        'class'      => 'CFileLogRoute',
                        'levels'     => 'info, warning, error',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    // application components
    'components' => array(
        // this class is used to simplify template actions
        'TemplateHelper' => array(
            'class'      => 'application.components.TemplateHelper',
        ),
        /* i18N - begin */
        'messages'   => array(
            'class'                  => 'CDbMessageSource',
            'onMissingTranslation'   => array('TranslateModule',
                'missingTranslation',
            ),
        ),
        'translate' => array(
            'class'              => 'translate.components.MPTranslate',
            'acceptedLanguages'  => array(
                'en'             => 'English',
                'nl'             => 'Nederlands',
            ),
        ),
        /* i18N - end */
        'authManager'    => array(
            'class'          => 'RDbAuthManager',
            'connectionID'   => 'db',
            'defaultRoles'   => array('authenticated', 'user'),
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'class'          => 'WebUser',
            /* enable cookie-based authentication */
            'allowAutoLogin' => true,
            /* @see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth */
            'loginUrl'       => array('/site/login'),
        ),
        'booster' => array(
            'class'          => 'booster.components.Bootstrap',
            'coreCss'        => true,
            'responsiveCss'  => true,
            'yiiCss'         => true,
            'minify'         => true,
        ),
    ),
    /** application-level parameters that can be accessed
     *  using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
     */
    'params'         => array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'         => 'beheer@momentum-technologies.nl',
        'cookie_duration'    => 3600 * 24 * 30,
        'composer.callbacks' => array(
            // args for Yii command runner
            'yiisoft/yii-install' => array('yiic', 'webapp', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..'),
            'post-update' => array('yiic', 'migrate'),
            'post-install' => array('yiic', 'migrate'),
        ),
    ),
);
$mainDbIncluded = CMap::mergeArray($config_database, $config_main);

// include and merge local main config if it exists
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/main-local.php'))
{
    return CMap::mergeArray($mainDbIncluded, include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/main-local.php'));
}
// otherwise just load the main config file
return $mainDbIncluded;
```

As you can see I have defined my CSS path to be:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('booster', $vendorPath . 'clevertech/yii-booster/src/'); // a twitter bootstrap library
```

here is my header.php that goe wrong:

```
<?php
$lang = Yii::app()->getLanguage();
if (empty($lang))
{
    $lang = 'en';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/widgets/jui.tabs.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/css/common.css" />
        <?php
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/common.js');
        ?>
        <title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/widgets/jui.tabs.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="header">
            <?php
            $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbNavbar', array(
            'brand' => '<img src="' . Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/images/logo_mte.png" alt="" />' ,
            'brandUrl' => '#',
            'collapse' => true,
            'type' => null,
            'items' => array(
                'brand' =>  Yii::App()->name ,
                array(
                    'class' => 'booster.widgets.TbMenu',
                    'items' => array(
                        array('label'    => 'Login', 'url'   => array('/site/login'), 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                        array('label'    => 'Logout (' . Yii::app()->user->name . ')', 'url'     => array('/site/logout'), 'visible' => !Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
                    ),
                ),
            )));
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="ajaxLoading">
            <!--<img src="../public/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..."/>-->
        </div>
```

an when I look at my inspect element in chrome this is what I see:

as you can see it is generated in assets. but I dont want it to be like this how can I fix that?

But it doesn't use this one and instead, it uses an incorrect version. Can someone help me out with this? Maybe I am getting this wrong and the problem is from something else. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I experienced many CSS issues when working with the Booster extension before, re-installing it following those steps fixed them for me at that time:

> 1. Get [YiiBoilerplate](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/374/yiiboilerplate-setup-a-professional-project-structure-in-seconds/)
>      and unzip it somewhere, it's created by the same guys at clevertech
>      and using the booster extension by default.
> 2. Go to {unzipped}backend/views/layouts/ and grab main.php,
>      column1.php and column2.php
> 3. create a new theme in your webapp under the /themes folder (I called
>      it 'booster')
> 4. Copy the three files from (3) into themes/booster/views/layouts In
>      your main.php add 'theme' => 'booster' as a top-level entry of the
>      array (I put it first)

That was @TeacherT solution that worked out for me after posting [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468373/yiibooster-theme-not-working), other solutions has came out later and seemed to solve the CSS issues to other users, so you may try them too.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: you're right @rink.attendant.6 it is better this way